# Can i change signed android project package name?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have an android project and the package is signed. When I want to change the package name, I get a "runtime exception" error. Is there any way to get rid of this signature?

Comment: When you change the package name, you have to change it everywhere. Build.gradle, manifest, java/kotlin classes and in xml files if you are using it there. Add the exception error to the question.

Comment: I already did it :( This project package is signed.

Comment: I don't think signing the apk is a problem. Are there any logs that we can look through?

Comment: Not an APK, its package. This projects have a public key so i can't change the package name.

Comment: Check your proguard for any class or model, there is not issue in changing package name of signed apk. but you must need to change it at all place.

Comment: Is there anything I should pay attention to?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio then use Refactoring instead of simply renaming Package Name. Right click on Package>Refactor>Rename.
Still better option is to create a new Project with your required Package Name and Copy all Java Classes and Resources to New Project.

Comment: I tried this method but it didn't work. When I make changes to package names, I get a "runtime exception" error.

Comment: Run time exception means that all the package names are not changed to the new package. you can use find and Replace command inside new package to change old package names